# Center Image from a table row

Tags: html, css

[image: What i need to obtain]

Hi guys I just need a lil help from you i couldn't get the image to the center of the two table row. here what i've got so far. Please see the photos for the reference . The first photo is what i need to obtain while the second photo is what i obtain .
[image: What i obtain so far]

```css
/* Basics */

body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}

td {
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}

div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(95, 89, 89);
}

.webkit {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.outer {
  Margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.full-width-image img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.inner {
  padding: 20px;
}

.inner-footer {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: unset;
}

a {
  color: #ee6a56;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}


/* One column layout */

.one-column .contents {
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

.one-column p {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*Two column layout*/

.two-column {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.two-column .column {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.contents {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.two-column .contents {
  font-size: 14px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

.two-column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  height: auto;
}

.two-column .text {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/*Three column layout*/

.three-column {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.three-column .column {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.three-column .contents {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.three-column img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 180px;
  height: auto;
}

.three-column .text {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* Left sidebar layout */

.left-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.left-sidebar .column {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-sidebar .left {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.left-sidebar .right {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.left-sidebar .img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.left-sidebar .contents {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-sidebar a {
  color: #85ab70;
}


/* Right sidebar layout */

.right-sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.right-sidebar .column {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right-sidebar .left {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.right-sidebar .right {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.right-sidebar .img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.right-sidebar .contents {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right-sidebar a {
  color: #70bbd9;
}


/*Media Queries*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .two-column .column,
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .two-column img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .three-column img {
    max-width: 50% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 620px) {
  .three-column .column {
    max-width: 33% !important;
  }
  .two-column .column {
    max-width: 50% !important;
  }
}

.red-text {
  color: red;
}

.white-text {
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: blue;
}

.social-media {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.img-space {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.orange-text {
  color: #f5a123;
}

.package-box {
  padding: 15px;
}

.phone-numbers {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
]
<center class="wrapper">
  <div class="webkit">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
    <table>
      <tr style="background-image:url(https://...../assets/admin/images/step2camp/banner-bg-withcolor.jpg);background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;">
        <td class="one-column">
          <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class='inner contents' style="height: 60px;">
                  <center><img src="https://..../assets/admin/images/descamp/images/logo.png" style="width: 30%;float: left;" alt="" /></center>
                  <p style="color: white;float: right;text-align: right;padding-top: 12px;">
                    Phone Australia: +612-8488-8240<br \>Phone United Kingdom: +44-203-318-1017
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class='inner contents' style="text-align: center;">
                  <p style="font-size:16px;color:white;">GET A NEW WEBSITE THIS WEEK</p>
                  <p style="font-size:28px;color:#afd415;">SAVE $400</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class='inner contents' style="text-align: center;padding-bottom: 0px;">
                  <img src="https://..../assets/admin/images/step2camp/laptop.png" alt="" style="width:300px;height:200px;" />
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="background-color:#fff;">
        <td class="one-column">
          <div class="column">
            <table width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td style="height:100px;">

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

I'm making an email html module so i need to use a table for the formatting . Hope someone can help me with this - Cheers

Comment: Do you mean that you want the image of the laptop to straddle the two rows? That is what the top image appears to be doing as, looking at your code, you have a background image on the first row and background colour of white on the second row? If so, you will have to totally re-structure this. You can't do it with the two tables as you have it. (unless you could use absolute positioning but given this is for email I don't think you can).

Comment: @LeoFarmer so what magic should i do with this sir . does margin with negative value works on email templates?

Comment: I would look at sizing the background to cover a percentage of the cell that you are positioning your image in. e.g. background-size: 100% 70%

Comment: it works but the problem my upper logo is now half of it i can only see @LeoFarmer